# HttpRequest.TransportInformation not available in UWP app

Tags: validation, uwp, ssl-certificate, httpclient

I need to validate SSL certificate of a website in my UWP app, and I am following the method described at this URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/intro-to-secure-windows-app-development, but there is no TransportInformation property available under RequestMessage class in my IDE, and the intellisense complains about it too. I'm using VS2017, .NetCore 5.3.3, target Version 15063 min version 10586. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using [Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage) and not System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage. TransportInformation is a member of the Windows.Web version only.

You can use Visual Studio's object browser to help find which class a property is in. Browse "My Solution", search for TransportInformation, and the [Object Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/viewing-the-structure-of-code#BKMK_ObjectBrowser) will point you to Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Rob. It was a silly confusion on my part but I couldn't have solved it without you :)